# how to add attachments programatically to email in a windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 app , in that i want to add attachments to the email in my windows phone 8 app.

1)How can we add attachments(attaching files) to email and send ??

2)is that EmailComposeTask doesn't support attachments ?? ,if so What is the alternative ??

2)What are the various ways in which we can  attach files in windows phone 8 app??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently also asking myself these questions and found this demo library Ahmed mentioned. However, I wanted a solution without buying libraries.

If you are not using binary files, you can always put your files content to the body of the EmailComposeTask. The other possibility is to use SkyDrive and upload your file and just put the link to the file in the emails body.